# Validating values in n number of files

Tags: regex, perl

I have nearly 500 xhtml files i want to find the duplicate ids in all the files. Aim is fetch one file read an id="xxx" the same id should not present in remaining files. if found through error message the chapter1 id present  in some other chapter files.

I tried this result also came but takes to run the program nearly 15 minutes.
i want efficient coding please help.

```
foreach my $xhtml(@xhtml_files){
        my $htmlcnt = _open_file("$dirname\\$xhtml");
        my @Duplicate_xhtml_files = ();

        #-------------The external (ID) matched with (filename)-------------------
        @Duplicate_xhtml_files = _get_file_list($ARGV[0],1,0,'\.xhtml$',$xhtml); 
        my @array_ids = $htmlcnt =~ m{( id="[^>"]+")}isg;
        my $array_joinids = "##".join("##",@array_ids)."##";
        foreach my $file(@Duplicate_xhtml_files){
            my $duplicate_htmlcnt = _open_file("$dirname\\$file");
            while($duplicate_htmlcnt =~ m{( id="[^>"]+")}isg){
                my $pre = $`;   my $check_id = $1;
                if($array_joinids =~ m{\#\#$check_id\#\#}is){
                    ($ln, $cl) = LineCol($pre);
                    $Error .="\n\t[$ln:$cl]\: Error:[MV-1024]\: $file => The external ($check_id) matched with ($xhtml).\n";
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a sample of file content ? The answer is most likely "use a parser".

Comment: @depsai: I think rather than using arrays you can go with hashes in perl which will find the duplicate id's from various files easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Do as much work as you can outside the loop***.

You have loops in loops in loops (in hidden loops).  This is likely to be slow.

If there's 500 `@xhtml_files` and let's say there's 100 in `@Duplicate_xhtml_files` and maybe 100 `id`s in each file.  And let's not forget about searching `$array_joinids`, that's a hidden loop over that list of IDs!  Let's say there's 100 IDs in `$array_joinids`.

```
foreach my $xhtml (@xhtml_files) {
    ...500 times...
    foreach my $file(@Duplicate_xhtml_files) {
        ...50,000 times...
        while($duplicate_htmlcnt =~ m{( id="[^>"]+")}isg){
            ...5,000,000 times...

            # This is really looping over all the ids, so
            # you're looking at IDs 500,000,000 times.
            if($array_joinids =~ m{\#\#$check_id\#\#}is){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a guess, but you get the idea: doing work in an inner loop greatly magnifies the cost.  *Do everything you can as high up as possible*.

---

For example, if you need to find a specific element in a list that means you need to loop over the whole list.  You have too many loops in loops.  And you're doing it in a really obfuscated way by turning the list into a `##` delimited string (loop) and then searching that string over and over again with a regex (loop).

This...

```
my @array_ids = $htmlcnt =~ m{( id="[^>"]+")}isg;
my $array_joinids = "##".join("##",@array_ids)."##";

while($duplicate_htmlcnt =~ m{ id="([^>"]+)"}isg) {
    my $check_id = $1;
    if($array_joinids =~ m{\#\#$check_id\#\#}is) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is much better done as this...

```
my @ids = $htmlcnt =~ m{( id="[^>"]+")}isg;
while($duplicate_htmlcnt =~ m{ id="([^>"]+)"}isg) {
    my $check_id = $1;
    if( grep { $_ eq $check_id } @ids ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But that's still looping over all the IDs (the `grep`) in your critical inner loop.  You could make it a little faster using [List::Util::first](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#first) so it will stop on a match, but it's just rearranging chairs on the Titanic.  The real performance win is to get rid of that innermost loop.

Instead, use a hash.  Then you don't have to loop through all the IDs in the critical innermost loop, you can do a fast hash lookup instead.  Hash lookups are the same speed no matter how many elements they have.

```
# Also only store the ID, not all the HTML around it.
my %ids = map { $_ => 1 } = $htmlcnt =~ m{ id="([^>"]+)"}isg;

while($duplicate_htmlcnt =~ m{ id="([^>"]+)"}isg) {
    my $check_id = $1;
    if( $ids{$check_id} ) {
        ...it's a duplicate!...
    }
}
```

---

Another obvious target is to eliminate all that inner inner inner loops all together.  Scan all the files once, store all their IDs, and THEN check for duplicates using `%all_ids`.  This avoids possibly parsing the same XHTML files multiple times.

```
# This will hold what IDs are in what files.
my %all_ids;

# Record which IDs are in which files.
for my $xhtml (@all_xhtml_files) {
     ...
     while( $htmlcnt =~ m{ id="([^>"]+)"}isg ) {
         $all_ids{$1}{$xhtml} = 1;
     }
}

# Now go through the list of IDs and look for ones that are in
# more than one file.
for my $id (keys %all_ids) {
    my $in_files = $all_ids{$id};
    if( @$in_files > 1 ) {
        print "Duplicate ID $id seen in @$in_files";
    }
}
```

You'll have to modify that for the details of your duplicate detection, but you get the idea.

---

Incidentally, unless you're using Perl 5.20 when they fixed this, don't use `` $` ``.  It can severely slow down all regexes.  See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for details and alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, with or without using perl.
If you want to use perl you have a couple of options:

- Read all of the files and set an hash key for all of the IDs, increasing the value every time you encounter the ID. This way you would have to read every file once, but for 500 files of, say, 500k each, my guess is that it would take less than a minute. You didn't show the complete program, so this is an approximation, but it's something like:

`

```
use File::Slurp;
my %id_values;
foreach my $file (@xhtml_files @Duplicate_xhtml_files) {
    my @lines = read_file("$file");
    my $line_index = 1;
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        my @array_ids = $line =~ m{( id="[^>"]+")}isg;
        my $id = '##'.join('##',@array_ids).'##';
        push @{$id_values{$id}}, { $file => $line_index };
        $line_index++;
    }
}
foreach my $key (keys(%id_values)) {
    if (@{$id_values} > 1) {
        foreach my $dup (@{$id_values}) {
            print $key . ':: ' . $file . ' - ' . $line;
        }
    }
}
```

`

This is not tested, but it should give you the general idea.

- Sort the files before parsing them, so you can use a binary search to find duplicates. This will take longer the first time you run it, but it will be faster in case you need to run it multiple times. Writing a binary search function can be tricky, but [there's a CPAN module](http://search.cpan.org/~rant/Search-Binary/Binary.pm) .

Without using perl you can use bash to determine the values and then grep them. Something like:

```
cat *.xhtml |cut -d'=' -f2 |sort uniq -c |sort >> duplicate_ids.txt
```

(The "cut" command is approximate since you didn't provide an example)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'd suggest that rather than doing what you're doing, the answer is 'use a parser'.

The problem is that without better sample input, I can't give you a clearer answer, but it'd be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my %seen;

sub seen_id {
    my ( $twig, $tag ) = @_;
    my $id = $tag->att('id');
    $tag -> print;
    return unless $id;
    print "Duplicate spotted $id", if $seen{$id}++;
}

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { 'tag[@id]' => \&seen_id } ); 

foreach my $xhtml ( glob "*.xhtml" ) {
    $twig -> parsefile ( $xhtml ); 
}

print join ( "\n", sort keys %seen );
```

Depending on the size of my `xhtml` files, I might do something like purge/discard/early bailout. (Disk IO will usually be the limiting factor).

Or perhaps instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my %seen;

foreach my $xhtml ( glob "*.xhtml" ) {
    my $twig = XML::Twig -> new(); 
    $twig -> parsefile ( $xhtml ); 
    #get the first element (of any) with an 'id' attribute) 
    my $id = $twig -> get_xpath('//*[@id]',0) -> att('id'); 
    print "$xhtml is a dupe\n" if $seen{$id}++; 
}

print join ( "\n", sort keys %seen );
```